# Get-ChildItem object note properties strings have 5 additonal hidden characters?

Tags: powershell

When I run `Get-ChildItem` for some path with jpg files I am then trying to check the string length of one of the several name properties (name of the file). I keep getting 5 additional hidden characters in string length and I don't understand why it is happening.

I am running PowerShell 5 in Windows 10 on VS Code. It only seems to be an issue with the note properties for the object that are strings. If I do same on the `Length` property by first casting to string I get the correct length.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path [some folder path] -Name |
    Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -like '*2006‎03‎14‏‎1843_IMG*' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Length }
```

Output:

```
27
27
```

Example 2:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Mattias\Desktop\bilder\duplicates" |
    Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -like '*2006‎03‎14‏‎1843_IMG*' } |
    Select-Object PSChildName, @{n="name_length";e={$_.PSChildName.Length}}
```

Output:

```
PSChildName            name_length
-----------            -----------
‎2006‎03‎14‏‎1843_IMG_2.JPG          27
‎2006‎03‎14‏‎1843_IMG_3.JPG          27
```

I was expecting string length to be 22 but it seems to be getting 5 additional characters that are not visible. Same 5 hidden characters on `Name`, `PSChildName`, `BaseName`, etc. When I have tried doing wildcard filtering I have noticed it only produces output if I include `*` (star) before object name so probably the hidden characters are preceding (leading). Is there some bug or configuration for turning this off I am not aware of?

---

Edit: Per user @Ansgar Wiechers request. Output of his code change:

```
200e 32 30 30 36 200e 30 33 200e 31 34 200f 200e 31 38 34 33 5f 49 4d 47 5f 32 2e 4a 50 47
200e 32 30 30 36 200e 30 33 200e 31 34 200f 200e 31 38 34 33 5f 49 4d 47 5f 33 2e 4a 50 47
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Mattias\Desktop\bilder\duplicates" | ?{$_.PSChildName -like '*2006‎03‎14‏‎1843_IMG*'} | %{([int[]][char[]]$_.PSChildName | %{'{0:x2}' -f $_}) -join ' '}`.

Comment: Do you get the same result with the `Name` property? ie. `Get-ChildItem -Path [some folder path] |Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*2006‎03‎14‏‎1843_IMG*' } |ForEach-Object { $_.Name.Length }`?

Comment: You can get rid of these format characters (General Punctiation Block) using `@{n="name_length";e={($_.Name -creplace '\p{IsGeneralPunctuation}').Length}}`

Comment: @Theo: Thank you! Not sure why MS decided this was a reasonable default but your solution solved my issue.

Comment: The output I requested was needed for debugging the issue. Please do not remove it from the question. Also, I doubt that Windows is adding these characters by default. It certainly never has done that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some *format* characters in provided file names (no clue where those chars come from):

```
. .\_get-CharInfo_1.1.ps1
'‎2006‎03‎14‏‎1843_IMG_3.JPG' | Get-CharInfo
```

> ```
> Char CodePoint             Category Description           
> ---- ---------             -------- -----------           
>    ‎ U+200E                  Format Left-To-Right Mark    
>    2 U+0032      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Two             
>    0 U+0030      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Zero            
>    0 U+0030      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Zero            
>    6 U+0036      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Six             
>    ‎ U+200E                  Format Left-To-Right Mark    
>    0 U+0030      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Zero            
>    3 U+0033      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Three           
>    ‎ U+200E                  Format Left-To-Right Mark    
>    1 U+0031      DecimalDigitNumber Digit One             
>    4 U+0034      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Four            
>    ‏ U+200F                  Format Right-To-Left Mark    
>    ‎ U+200E                  Format Left-To-Right Mark    
>    1 U+0031      DecimalDigitNumber Digit One             
>    8 U+0038      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Eight           
>    4 U+0034      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Four            
>    3 U+0033      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Three           
>    _ U+005F    ConnectorPunctuation Low Line              
>    I U+0049         UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter I
>    M U+004D         UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter M
>    G U+0047         UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter G
>    _ U+005F    ConnectorPunctuation Low Line              
>    3 U+0033      DecimalDigitNumber Digit Three           
>    . U+002E        OtherPunctuation Full Stop             
>    J U+004A         UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter J
>    P U+0050         UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter P
>    G U+0047         UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter G
> ```

(Output from modified `Get-CharInfo` cmdlet.) Original `Get-CharInfo` module is downloadable from http://poshcode.org/5234.
 **Unfortunately, the link is dead**; here is full code:

```
<#
_get-CharInfo_1.1.ps1

Origin   by: http://poshcode.org/5234
             sorry, the above link is not available; last time checked 2018-05-07
Improved by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz

Use this like this: "ábč",([char]'x'),0xBF | Get-CharInfo

Activate dot-sourced like this (apply a real path instead of .\):

. .\_get-CharInfo_1.1.ps1

#>

Add-Type -Name UName -Namespace Microsofts.CharMap -MemberDefinition $(
    switch ("$([System.Environment]::SystemDirectory -replace 
                '\\', '\\')\\getuname.dll") {
    {Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf} {@"
[DllImport("${_}", ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int GetUName(ushort wCharCode, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder buf);

public static string Get(char ch) {
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(300);
    UName.GetUName(ch, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
"@
    }
    default {'public static string Get(char ch) { return "???"; }'}
    })

function Get-CharInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject],[System.Array])]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $InputObject
    )
    begin {
        Set-StrictMode -Version latest
        function out {
            param(
                [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true )] $ch,
                [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]$nil=''
                 )
            if (0 -le $ch -and 0xFFFF -ge $ch) {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char = [char]$ch
                    CodePoint = 'U+{0:X4}' -f $ch
                    Category = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($ch)
                    Description = [Microsofts.CharMap.UName]::Get($ch)
                }
            } elseif (0 -le $ch -and 0x10FFFF -ge $ch) {
                $s = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($ch)
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char = $s
                    CodePoint = 'U+{0:X}' -f $ch
                    Category = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($s, 0)
                    Description = '???' + $nil
                }
            } else {
                Write-Warning ('Character U+{0:X} is out of range' -f $ch)
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        if ($PSBoundParameters['Verbose']) {
            Write-Warning "InputObject type = $($InputObject.GetType().Name)"}
        if ($null -cne ($InputObject -as [char])) {
            #Write-Verbose "A $([char]$InputObject) InputObject character"
            out $([int][char]$InputObject) ''
        } elseif ($InputObject -isnot [string] -and $null -cne ($InputObject -as [int])) {
            #Write-Verbose "B $InputObject InputObject"
            out $([int]$InputObject) ''
        } else {
            $InputObject = [string]$InputObject
            #Write-Verbose "C $InputObject InputObject.Length $($InputObject.Length)"
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $InputObject.Length; ++$i) {
                if (  [char]::IsHighSurrogate($InputObject[$i]) -and 
                      (1+$i) -lt $InputObject.Length -and 
                      [char]::IsLowSurrogate($InputObject[$i+1])) {
                    $aux = ' 0x{0:x4},0x{1:x4}' -f [int]$InputObject[$i], 
                                                   [int]$InputObject[$i+1]
                    Write-Verbose "surrogate pair $aux at position $i" 
                    out $([char]::ConvertToUtf32($InputObject[$i], $InputObject[1+$i])) $aux
                    $i++
                } else {
                    out $([int][char]$InputObject[$i]) ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunate the length command picks up those hidden format characters since length should, in my view, count only that which user can see. Else we get these situations. I am able to remove specific unichar characters with trim command but really should not have to(opinion).